# Javascript object declaration issue

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm digging OOP for the first time but I've got a little problem:

```
var panel = {    
    img : imgs[24],
    prop : this.img.height / this.img.width,

    h : this.img.height - (scale),
    w : h/prop,

    x : center.x - (w / 2),
    y : center.y - (h / 2)    
}

panel.draw = function(){    
   g.ctx.drawImage(this.img,
      0, 0,
      this.img.width, this.img.height,
      this.x, this.y,
      this.w, this.h)
}
```

But it looks like declaring `this.img.height` results in `typeError`. Can someone explain why?

Also, how can I declare the method *inside* the object declaration? Nothing special about it: I just don't want my code to look too messy.

Comment: I may have missed something, but what is "scale" in this example referring to?

Comment: don't worry: it is a variable declared elsewhere in the code :) I could remove it but I would still get the same typeError

Comment: What kind of objects are stored in the "imgs" array?

Comment: Hint: `this` is not the object you are look^H^H^H^H trying to refer to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your object always static to the name panel? Then

```
var panel = {};
panel.img = imgs[24];
panel.prop = panel.img.height / panel.img.width;
...
```

Is it not static but you don't want instances of it? Then make an initialisation function to get the correct `this`

```
var panel = {   // assuming "scale" and "center" in scope
        init : function(){
            this.img = imgs[24];
            this.prop = this.img.height / this.img.width;
            this.h = this.img.height - (scale);
            this.w = this.h / this.prop;
            this.x = center.x - (this.w / 2);
            this.y = center.y - (this.h / 2);
        }
};
panel.init();
...
```

Do you want to have multiple instances of the object? Then make a *constructor*

```
function Panel (img) { // assuming "scale" and "center" in scope
    this.img = img;
    this.prop = img.height / img.width;
    this.h = img.height - (scale);
    this.w = this.h / this.prop;
    this.x = center.x - (this.w / 2);
    this.y = center.y - (this.h / 2);
}
Panel..draw = function(){
...
```

and use with `var panel = new Panel( imgs[24] );`

Comment: This won't work `prop : panel.img.height / panel.img.width`. You can't refer to an object during its instantiation when using literal syntax. During its creation, `panel` will be `undefined`.

Comment: everything have much more sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are refering to different object even if thinking you are not doing that. So in your example, on third line `this` is refering current scope and not the object panel you are creating. So do `img` and `h`

```
var panel = {    
    img : imgs[24],
    prop : this.img.height / this.img.width, // this != panel here

    h : this.img.height - (scale), // this.img != panel.img
    w : h/prop, // h != panel.h

    x : center.x - (w / 2), // w != panel.w
    y : center.y - (h / 2)  // h != panel.h  
}

panel.draw = function(){    
   g.ctx.drawImage(this.img,
      0, 0,
      this.img.width, this.img.height,
      this.x, this.y,
      this.w, this.h)
}
```

Should be something like

```
var Panel = (function() {    
    function Panel(img, scale, center) {  
       this.img = img
       this.prop = img.height / img.width
       this.h = img.height - scale
       this.w = this.h/this.prop
       this.x = center.x - (this.w / 2),
       this.y = center.y - (this.h / 2)
    }
    Panel.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
          ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0,
          this.img.width, this.img.height,
          this.x, this.y,this.w, this.h)
    }          
})():

var panel = new Panel(imgs[24], scale, center);
panel.draw(g.ctx);
```

Comment: This could have been a comment, given you don't actually solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `this` will never be a reference to the object you're creating when using *object literal* syntax.

It's a reference to the outer variable scope. To use literal syntax, you'll need to create the parts that do not require a self reference, then create rest after the initialization.

```
var panel = {    
    img : imgs[24],

    w : h/prop,

    x : center.x - (w / 2),
    y : center.y - (h / 2)    
};
panel.prop = panel.img.height / panel.img.width;
panel.h = panel.img.height - scale;
```

I don't know what your `h` and `prop` variables are supposed to refer to.

If you expect them to refer to members of the object, then you need to take those out as well. And the `center` variable just seems to come out of nowhere.

Seems like maybe you're just guessing at how JavaScript syntax works. If so, that's a hard way to learn. I'd recommend a basic tutorial before you continue.

Answer (score 0):

Panel object doesn't have panel.img.height property.

```
var panel = {    
    img :
        { height: // stuff here
        }
    prop : this.img.height / this.img.width,

    h : this.img.height - (scale),
    w : h/prop,

    x : center.x - (w / 2),
    y : center.y - (h / 2)    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the context in which `panel` is declared, not the panel object itself. A few workarounds :

Cache the referred object :

```
var img = imgs[24];
var panel = {
    img: img
  , height: img.height - scale
  , //...
```

Create a blank panel object and add properties one by one :

```
var panel = {};
panel.img = imgs[24]
panel.height = panel.img - scale;
```

And methods can be declared like any other property.

```
var panel = {
    img: imgs[24]
  , draw: function(){ g.ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0) }
}
```